# if constexpr vs sfinae

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

With the introduction of `if constexpr` in `c++17`, some problems which were solved by using compile-time SFINAE in `c++14`/`c++11` can now be solved using `if constexpr`, with an easier syntax.

Consider, e.g., the following basic example of a compile-time recursion to produce a subroutine which prints a variable number of arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void print_sfinae(T&& x)
{
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

template <typename T0, typename... T>
std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(T) > 0)> print_sfinae(T0&& x, T&&... rest)
{
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  print_sfinae(std::forward<T>(rest)...);
}

template <typename T0, typename... T>
void print_ifconstexpr(T0&&x, T&&... rest)
{
  if constexpr (sizeof...(T) > 0)
         {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
            print_ifconstexpr(std::forward<T>(rest)...);
         }
  else
      std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  print_sfinae(5, 2.2, "hello");
  print_ifconstexpr(5, 2.2, "hello");

  return 0;
}
```

The routine `print_sfinae` uses SFINAE techniques from `c++11`, whereas `print_ifconstexpr` does the same job by using `if constexpr`.

Can one assume that the compiler, on evaluating the `if constexpr` completely discards the non-verified condition and generate code only for the branch which satisfy the `if constexpr` condition? Does the standard specifies such a behavior for the compiler?

More generally, in terms of efficiency and generated code, are solutions based on `if constexpr` identical to the equivalent solutions based on pre-c++17 SFINAE?

Comment: Not what you asked about, but variadic `print` can be written as a non-recursive one-liner if you use C++17 fold expressions. Pre-C++17 the same thing could be accomplished using the dummy array trick.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *dummy array trick* = ?

Comment: @Walter: `int dummy[] = {0, ((std::cout << xs << std::endl), 0)...}; static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused var`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can one assume that the compiler, on evaluating the `if constexpr` completely discards the non-verified condition and generate code only for the branch which satisfy the `if constexpr` condition? Does the standard specifies such a behavior for the compiler?

The standard specifies that, from [[stmt.if]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#2.sentence-3):

> If the `if` statement is of the form `if constexpr`, the value of the condition shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type `bool`; this form is called a *constexpr if* statement. If the value of the converted condition is `false`, the first substatement is a discarded statement, otherwise the second substatement, if present, is a discarded statement. During the instantiation of an enclosing templated entity, if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement (if any) is not instantiated.

The point here is that the discard statement is *not instantiated* - this is the whole purpose behind `if constexpr` as a language feature, to allow you to write:

```
template <typename T0, typename... T>
void print_ifconstexpr(T0&& x, T&&... rest)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(T) > 0) {
        print_ifconstexpr(std::forward<T>(rest)...);
    }
}
```

You can't do that with a simple `if`, because that would still require instantiating the substatements - even if the condition can be determined to be `false` at compile time. A simple `if` would require the ability to call `print_ifconstexpr()`.

`if constexpr` will not instantiate the recursive call unless there is something in `rest...`, so this works.

Everything else follows from the lack of instantiation. There can't be any generated code for the discarded statement.

The `if constexpr` form is easier to write, easier to understand, and surely compiles faster. Definitely prefer it.

---

Note that your first example doesn't need the SFINAE at all. This works just fine:

```
template <typename T>
void print(T&& x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

template <typename T0, typename... T>
void print(T0&& x, T&&... rest)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    print(std::forward<T>(rest)...);
}
```

As does:

```
void print() { }

template <typename T0, typename... T>
void print(T0&& x, T&&... rest)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    print(std::forward<T>(rest)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ specifies program observable behaviour.

Both pieces of code have as observable behaviour printing.

Copying references, calling functions that take references and return void, are both not observable behaviour.

Both functions have identical obserable behaviour.  So the C++ standard has zilch to say about any differences in runtime, code size or memory usabe between them.